# React native not installing in windows

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new in react native, whenever I am try to install react native using command `create-react-native-app MyReactNative` It's showing an error

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Do you have Android Studio installed? I also recommend to read [this article](https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/create-a-react-native-app-on-an-android-emulator-1c0d94f288ae)

Comment: Did u try installing expo? Here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/installation/

Comment: I am not sure this is only me, but I simply cannot read your printscreen. Can you upload a better one (bigger)?

Answer (score 1):

```
    paste this command in cmd administrator level
==============================================================
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"


choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8.

npm install –g react-native-cli



=========================================================
choco link
https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/installing-the-chocolatey-package-manager-for-windows-3b1bdd0dbb49

node link 
https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v10.16.3/

java link 
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk14-archive-downloads.html

vistual studio

ANDROID_HOME      :- sdk path
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT  :- sdk path
JAVA_HOME    :-   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144  without bin
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is [2 ways](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) of creating a react-native app.

One is using [Expo](https://expo.io/learn) and the other is using React Native CLI.

Looking at the error, it looks like you don't have expo installed.

You need to install Expo globally in order to use `create-react-native-app`.

Maybe `npm install expo-cli --global` will help you .